# Android Layout Problems Nexus 4 and 6

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I know there are many layout questions out there for Android.

My problem is, I have two folders 'layout' and 'layout-large'. Now the layout files fit perfectly on my Note 3 and Nexus 6P as well as the 6 (there is a bit of difference between the 6P and 6 but it still displays relatively how I need it with nothing overlapping). The large works well with my Nexus 7. Now when I use my Nexus 4 (emulator) and run my application, whilst the majority of the features show correctly (using Relative layout for them all), some things are overlapping and out of place.

I have tried using folders such as layout-w320dp etc, but the problem with this is then the Nexus 6 will also use this layout so again I am in the same problem. Whilst all the drawables are fine (I made them a size so it looks good on all screens), just the positioning of various components must be changed on devices like Nexus 4 and 5.

Any help?

Edit: Images of how it looks on a Nexus 6 emulator and Nexus 4 emulator

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RXWA.jpg

Comment: For Relative Layout to work properly you have to align them properly according to all devices. In Android Studio you can see your layout preview for almost dozen's of phone at a time, so I would suggest you to use that and use linear layout wherever possible as relative layout tends to break with different resolution

Comment: I've been trying to use LinearLayout but it still changes depending on the device.

Comment: provide a screenshot of both devices with same layout

Answer (score 0):

Best way to support multiple screen sizes and resolutions is to use configuration qualifiers for your layout and dimension folders.

You can find more info here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Hope it helps!